# Regex to check if string has at least 2 numbers and 1 capital letter

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I need to create a regular expression to check if a password has at least 1 uppercase letter, at least 2 numbers, and ends with a $ (dollar sign).

I've been trying to figure it out, but I can only get as far as checking if there's at least 1 uppercase and one number, rather than two.

***These should be valid:***

4hg5Fjkjk$

fh@#Y5fFF5$

hgH5Hu6$

***These should not be valid:***

45tyghisu$ (No capital)

5THygfhy$  (Only one number)

Gh%hF45$h  (No dollar sign at the end)

Here's what I have so far (checks for at least one number, one capital and dollar sign at the end)

`/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*\$/`
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ps. I've looked on SO, and can't find anything relating to more than one required character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the answers. Looked through them, and I figured out a pretty simple way to do it using the regular expression below. I edited it to allow for setting a length on the password, just change the 9 and 15 to your desired lengths.

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d.*\d)[^\s]{9,15}\$$/
```

Comment: With this pattern the third option does not match. I would suggest using `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` instead of  `(?=.*[A-Z])` as it uses [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast). You might  adjust my suggestion to `^(?=[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z])(?=(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){2})\S{9,15}\$$` to get a bit more efficient match https://regex101.com/r/turD46/1

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you have to repeat asserting a digit twice instead of one time using for example `(?=(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){2})` using [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).

If you don't want to allow spaces in the password, you could use `\S+` to match 1+ times a non whitespace char.

You could use:

```
^(?=[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z])(?=(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){2})\S+\$$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xF28PJ/1)

According to the given answer by the OP, the number of characters should be 9-15:

```
^(?=[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z])(?=(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){2})\S{9,15}\$$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/turD46/1)

Comment: It seems to me that you have `[^A-Z\r\n]` rather than the more obvious `.` as an artifact of the testing tool you are using (regx101.com) and the switches `g` and `m` that are in effect. But a real-world use of the regex would be to see if a single string, probably entered from a text input field, is a valid password and it does not make much sense to me (though not necessarily *detrimental*) to be  forbidding `\r` and `\n`. And does `?:` do anything in a lookahead specification?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson The `g` and `m` are only for displaying the multiple matches on regex101. Using `[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z]` makes use of the [contrast principle](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) While using the dot works, is causes unnecessary backtracking.

Comment: I got that `[^A-Z]*[A-Z]` *might* be more efficient than `.*[A-Z]` (it depends on the engine), but the `\r\n` are only in there because of your demo/testing tool. Your production code would not have it, would it?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson That is indeed for the demo tool. I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx is simple and makes no other assumptions about what characters may be in a password other than what was specified by the OP.

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d.*?\d).*\$$
```

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y51VtW/3) (Click ON "RUN TESTS")